# Related post Image is too blurry

Tags: image, blogger

In my blogger theme, When I open a post then the related post image appears too blurry with poor qualtiy. Blog - www.gadgetguild.ml

```
<div id='related_posts'>
<div class='relhead'>
  <h4>You might also like </h4>
<div class='clear'/>
<div class='relhead2'>
          <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
               <script expr:src='&quot;/feeds/posts/default/-/&quot; + data:label.name + &quot;?alt=json-in-script&amp;amp;callback=relpostimgcuplik&amp;amp;max-results=50&quot;' type='text/javascript'/>
       </b:loop>
          <ul id='relpost_img_sum'>
               <script type='text/javascript'>relatedposts();</script>
          </ul>
  </div>
     </div>
                          </div>
```

How can I fix this? Please Help!!